# Laravel saving radiobutton value with registration

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to add a radiobutton value into my users table. When the user registrate he can choose a "role" so I made 2 radiobuttons like this in my registration form:

```
{!! Form::radio('role', 'role1', true) !!}<br>
{!! Form::radio('role', 'role2') !!}
```

This is how I am trying to save the value in my AuthController. Unfortunately it does not work :'(. The role field stays empty and I get no errors.

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $role = Input::get('role');
            return User::create([
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
                'active' => 1,
                'role' => $role,
            ]); 
    }
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What type is column `role` in your database? Can you add a `Log::info($role);` check your laravel.log and post it here?

Comment: @Daan I've found the issue I forgot to add 'role' as a fillable in my Users model!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$data['role']`. This will get the value from the radio buttons.

You can use this:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $role = $data['role'];
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'active' => 1,
        'role' => $role,
    ]); 
}
```

Or you can use this:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'active' => 1,
        'role' => $data['role'],
    ]); 
}
```

---

And make sure that `role` is fillable in your `User` model.

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'active','role'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change statement

```
 $role = Input::get('role');
```

to

```
 $role = Input::get('role') ? 1 : 0;
```

Hope this helps!